# Getting old attribute value into entity hooks before_update() in ponyORM

Tags: python, ponyorm

I have the following db classes:

```
class Account(db.Entity):
    id = PrimaryKey(int, auto=True)
    name = Required(str)
    balance = Required(Decimal, precision=2, default=0)
    transactions = Set('Transaction')


class Transaction(db.Entity):
    id = PrimaryKey(int, auto=True)
    datetime = Required(datetime, precision=0, default=lambda: datetime.now())
    account = Required(Account)
    value = Required(Decimal, precision=2)
    description = Optional(str)

    def after_insert(self):
        self.account.balance += self.value

    def before_delete(self):
        self.account.balance -= self.value

    def before_update(self):
        pass
```

I did not find a way to reduce the balance like:

```
def before_update(self):
    self.account.balance += self.value - self.value.old_value
```

Is there any way to get the old attribute value?

Comment: AFAIK, before_update has not yet modified the value so the "old value" is still the "current value"

Comment: I checked: before_update() and after_update() have the same value

Answer (score 0):

I found a loophole:

```
class Account(db.Entity):
    id = PrimaryKey(int, auto=True)
    name = Required(str)
    balance = Required(Decimal, precision=2, default=0)
    transactions = Set('Transaction')


class Transaction(db.Entity):
    id = PrimaryKey(int, auto=True)
    datetime = Required(datetime, precision=0, default=lambda: datetime.now())
    account = Required(Account)
    value = Required(Decimal, precision=2)
    description = Optional(str)

    def after_insert(self):
        self.account.balance += self.value

    def before_delete(self):
        self.account.balance -= self.value

    def before_update(self):
        self._old_value = self._dbvals_[Transaction.value]

    def after_update(self):
        self.account.balance += self.value - self._old_value
```